# Using curved_navigation_bar package for navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to use custom Navigation bar and after using it I was getting this following error So I want to know why I am getting it , because the same thing was given in documentation itself.

[image]

Comment: this is the link to documentation https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar/example

Comment: Have you imported the library?

Comment: yes already added it

Comment: Can you show what your imports look like at the top of this file?

Comment: import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

import 'homepage.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as path_provider;
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';

Comment: The import looks right to me. Maybe try `flutter pub get`, `flutter clean`, and restart the app.

Comment: Thanks , I got it , I have to do some updating part since the version was not uptodate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to do some `updating` part since the version was not uptodate.
So I have updated the package and `restart` the application.